# Changing the number of results in the tensorflow object_detection tutorial

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have been working on the object_detection tutorial of tensorflow:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

The part, where the actual detection happens is:

```
  # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
  boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
  # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
  # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
  scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
  classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
  num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
  # Actual detection.
  (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
      [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

However, every result-tensor, i.e. boxes, scores and classes is exactly 100 entries long and I cannot find the slightest clue, where this number might be defined, yet I would like to change it.

Could anyone please provide me this informations or hints where to look into?

Best regards,

G.Brown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using frozen graph, you don't have the control to change the way graph do the predictions. To get the desired results, you can use hard thresholding to reduce the number of bounding boxes and false positives.

```
Suppose you want the predictions to be 80% sure than use thresholding to remove all prediction with `scores < 0.8`
```

Note: You can control this another way; for this, you need to get the original checkpoint files and use the export_inference_graph file. You need to change the line number 132-133. Same concept applies for other model configs ffiles. 
   [mobile ssd config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config#L132)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I will have to search for the .conf of the full model. As I see, they only provide them for the sub-versions such as for the linked pet-model of yours.